# Как можно оптимизировать строку для большего количества слов?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, match

Как можно оптимизировать строку для большего количества слов?
Например <html>, </html> и т.д.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, @"\bhtml\b");
            foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            }
```

Comment: Может, вам все теги убрать надо?

Comment: Мне надо сделать подсветку всех тэгов. Как это через regex сделать?

Comment: Если задумаете делать сложный парсинг на основе регулярных выражениях, просто вспомните про это обсуждение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если подсветить все одни цветом, то нам необходимо регулярное выражение поиска тегов в тексте, оно позволит нам пройтись по всем тегам и раскрасить их (в один цвет).
Если разными цветами, тогда придется использовать несколько регулярных выражений для того, чтобы определить, в какой цвет закрашивать тот или иной элемент (или как-то еще извратиться).

Закрашиваем первую часть тега:

Общая форма:

```
    \<{тут название тега}\>
```

Пример:

```
    \<html\> или \<head\>
```

Смысл понятен, в общем.

Закрашиваем вторую часть тега:

Общая форма:

```
    \<\/{тут название тега}\>
```

Пример:

```
    \<\/html\> или \<\/head\>
```

Но можно воспользоваться готовым компонентом [(FastColoredTextBox)](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov) для решения этой и многих других задач, связанных с подсветкой синтаксиса.
Ну, как вариант посмотреть, как он подошел к реализации данной задачи, и сделать что-то своё.